# Does the range of probable trajectories of a fermion particle change with its velocity/momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

My understanding is that if a fermion particle is shot out of a particle gun towards a measurement apparatus, the particle can take a variety of paths (or even all possible paths) that are uncertain (based on uncertainty principle) until the particle hits the measurement apparatus.  I believe there are equations (Schrodinger?) to determine the probable values of the wave function and the probabilities of hitting the apparatus in a given location.

My question is: Does the plotted surface area of probable  "landing spots" on the target measurement apparatus get larger or smaller depending on the velocity or momentum of the particle coming out of the gun?

Follow-up question:  Has the answer -- which, based on the first answer below seems to indicate the surface area of the landing plots decreases with an increase in speed/momentum -- been experimentally confirmed? Has it also been confirmed with high-energy fermion particles like those in a particle accelerator?  My understanding is that particle accelerators shoot out a LOT of particles at one time vs. isolating the particles one at a time like you might see coming out of a particle gun that might be a university science lab?

Comment: I am also not sure if the question makes sense, but any dependence on *absolute* velocities would break relativity. You can also note that as is consistent with this only spreads in momentum enter into the Heisenberg principle.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are firing the particles out of a gun with some muzzle diameter $d$:

[image: Particle beam]

If the beam momentum is $\mathbf p$ then we can split this into a component $p_x$ parallel to the beam gun and a component $p_y$ perpendicular to the beam gun. In an ideal world the beam would come out completely straight and wouldn't diverge at all, so $p_y=0$ and the beam creates a spot on the screen with diameter $d$. By making $d$ smaller we can make the spot as small as we want.

But by making the diameter of the beam gun $d$ we are localising the particles to within a region of size $d$ in the $y$ direction, i.e. $\Delta y = d$, and the uncertainty principle tells us that:

$$ \Delta y \Delta p_y \ge \frac{\hbar}{2} $$

and therefore the perpendicular momentum $p_y$ has a minimum value:

$$ \Delta p_y \ge \frac{\hbar}{2d} $$

This tells us that the beam must spread out due to the uncertainty principle. The angle of spread will be given by:

$$ \tan\theta \approx \frac{p_y}{p_x} \approx \frac{\hbar}{2dp_x} \tag{1} $$

where I've used the approximately equal symbol because this is a somewhat handwaving argument and should be regarded as an estimate. The exact spot size will depend on the beam profile and the gun to screen distance.

Anyhow we can now answer your question because we have:

$$ \tan\theta \propto \frac{1}{p_x} \propto \frac{1}{v_x} $$

because (in the non-relativistic regime) $v \propto p$. So the answer is that if we increase $v$ we decrease the spot size and vice versa.

There is another way to look at this. Suppose the beam was a light beam with some wavelength $\lambda$, then the beam spreads out due to diffraction and the image on the screen is an [Airy disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk) with a beam angle given by:

$$ \sin\theta \approx \frac{\lambda}{d} $$

Our particle beam has a [de Broglie wavelength](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/debrog2.html) given by:

$$ \lambda = \frac{h}{p} $$

and substituting this in the equation for the Airy disk gives:

$$ \sin\theta \approx \frac{h}{dp} $$

which is basically the same result as our equation (1) above.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram and the quick answer, John.  Seems to make sense.  I suppose the relativistic answer, considering mass and momentum variables and speeds close to the speed of light would complicate this answer?

Comment: @PurposeNation: the relativistic momentum is $p = \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$ so it does make things a bit more complicated though not impossibly so.

Comment: I think you should stress somewhere that you're computing here "spot size" as the area in which a certain percentage of the particles will fall, and that percentage is not 100% (one should be able to compute which it is from the usage of standard deviations, but it doesn't really matter). The question asks about "possible" not "probable" landing spots, and I'm not sure the asker is aware that the probability to find a particle outside your spot is non-zero.

Comment: Thanks, @ACuriousMind.  I have changed "possible" to "probable."  I don't know enough about the standard deviations to know how much a 90% probability vs. a 99% probability would change the area of the plot, but hopefully you get the idea of what I was asking from this.

Comment: @JohnRennie No need to do the relativistic calculations to get an exact number, but my understanding is that the plot area of the probable landing spots would decrease with an increase in momentum?  In other words, I don't think it changes the overall relationship whether or not the particle has mass and/or you use classical or relativistic calculations?  Or, when we reach near the speed of light for a fermion particle, is the particle more likely to do strange things, like quantum tunnel or evade detection all together?